# jQuery returning wrong height of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get the height of the `#header` element in my AngularJS application however jQuery seems to be returning the wrong height. At the moment the code basically consists of:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function resizeCover() {
        console.log($('#header').height());
    }

    resizeCover();
});
```

In console, I can see the output `20`, however that's not right, as can be seen from my highlighting the `#header` element with Chrome dev tools:

[image]

I've also tried using `outerHeight()` but that returns 20 as well.

The header makrup is as follows:

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <a ng-href="/">Company Ltd</a>
        </div>

        <ng-include src="'/partials/global-shared/navigation.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't think it's the `ng-include` that's causing trouble, as the `#logo` div is set to be a fixed height of 100px which should enlarge the height of `#header`.

What could be causing jQuery to return the wrong height of an element?

Comment: it could be because some contents are loaded after the height is calculated

Comment: The cause could be a timing issue (race condition) or CSS-related or Angular-related. If we don't have the whole picture, it is hard to find the problem. Preparing a fiddle or an **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)** would certainly help...

Comment: Yeah, setup a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ then we may be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're using angular, but the output of the height is on the document ready function.
Therefore, the browser console is outputting the height of the header before your ng-include is run.

Put your header console.log header into your angular app somewhere after the ng-include has been triggered.